# how to run a command on background on command line and how to rerun it automatically

Tags: windows, command-line, ffmpeg, cmd.exe

I have an windows server and I run a command on cmd with ffmpeg . I restream an hls with it . everything is good but sometimes because of source stream this command get stop . I want to know if there is any solution to run this command and when it stop it run again automatically . what should I do ?

this is my ffmpeg code :

```
ffmpeg -i http://test.m3u8 -c copy -segment_list_flags +live -hls_time 10 -hls_list_size 6 -hls_wrap 10 -segment_list_type m3u8 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -segment_time 10 output.m3u8
```

I think I should  use bat file . but I don't know how I should do this and integrate it with ffmpeg . Can someone help me on this case ? If you think my question is not correct  please don't give me a negative point.